# Using hotkey even if window hide in tray. Is it possible in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, hide, hotkeys, tray

I need to hide a form to the system tray, but in the same time I want to use hotkey, such a "ctrl+3" to get text from tEdit on my hiden form being inserted to Firefox SendText(edit1.Text); // in such method'. I know how to insert text, but i don't know anything about hotkeys/ Any suggestions? Thank you. Code of text inserting below

```
procedure SendText(const Value: WideString);
var
  I: Integer;
  S: WideString;
  TI: TInput;
  KI: TKeybdInput;
const
  KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = $0004;
begin
  S := WideUpperCase(Value); 
  TI.Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    KI.wVk := 0;
    KI.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    KI.wScan := Ord(S[I]);
    TI.ki := KI;
    SendInput(1, TI, SizeOf(TI));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Be aware that system wide hot keys can clash with application hot keys. For example ctrl+3 would stop one of the hot keys in my app from working. Give the user the option to customise system wide hot keys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To Register a system wide hotkey you must use the [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`UnRegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

Check this sample

```
type
  TForm125 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    HotKey1 : Integer;
    procedure WMHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey); message WM_HOTKEY;
  public

  end;

var
  Form125: TForm125;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm125.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HotKey1 := GlobalAddAtom('MyAppHotkey1');//create a unique value for identify the hotkey
  if not RegisterHotKey(Handle, HotKey1, MOD_CONTROL, VK_F1) then //register the hotkey CTRL + F1
   ShowMessage('Sorry can not register the hotkey');
end;

procedure TForm125.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnRegisterHotKey(Handle, HotKey1);//unregister the hotkey
  GlobalDeleteAtom(HotKey1);//remove the atom
end;

procedure TForm125.WMHotKey(var Msg: TWMHotKey);
begin
  if Msg.HotKey = HotKey1 then
    ShowMessage('Hello'); // do your stuff
end;
```

Just be carefull about the key combination which you choose, because can be used internally for another app. for example the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Number</kbd> is used by Firefox to switch the tabs.